# Getting user full location info with oAuth (facebook)

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, country, city

when I use FB connect I can retrieve a lot of user data, one of them being place_id

and connecting to
https://graph.facebook.com/112108272140707

I get the whole data, even the lon, lat... except for the (almost) most important part... COUNTRY... I know I could do another request to google maps or whatever to get the country, but I don;t wanna... I am sure I can get it from FB

any ideas?

Comment: read here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5143483/facebook-graph-api-how-to-get-user-country

Answer (score 1):

No, Facebook does not do geolcation in our API calls. We like small APIs that can be composed.