# Get user's country at Facebook: getSignedRequest() results without 'user' field

Tags: facebook

Code:

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
                'appId' => some_fb_app_id),
                'secret' => some_fb_app_secret),
                'cookie' => true,
            ));
$result = $facebook->getSignedRequest();
echo var_export($result,1);
```

Result:

```
array (
  'algorithm' => 'HMAC-SHA256',
  'code' => 'A.....l',
  'issued_at' => 1354720771,
  'user_id' => 'some_user_id',
)
```

I expect `$result["user"]["country"]` to be set. How can I fix this problem?

ps. by [Facebook Graph API - how to get user country?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5143483/facebook-graph-api-how-to-get-user-country)

Comment: It's customary to show you've put in some effort to solve your problem. Have you taken a look at the Facebook PHP SDK? I.e. http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/signed-request/

Answer (score 0):

According to [the facebook PHP SDK](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-getSignedRequest/) getSignedRequest() only gives you the signed request, just like the name suggests. User info is usually gotten through the Graph API, using calls like

```
$facebook->api('/me','GET');
```

which gives you the profile for the user associated with the access_token you are using.

Note that you will only ever get information that you have the permissions for, so if you haven't added a particular bit of info beyond the basics to your apps scope, you will not get it.

Comment: Using `$facebook->api('/me','GET');` I could receive 'location'

`array (
    'id' => '106045326100801',
    'name' => 'Dnipropetrovsk, Ukraine',
  ),`

But 'name' is just a location name - country is not strictly provided. Using 106045326100801 I could retrieve detailed location info - but country isn't strictly provided too.