# Getting user's country from Facebook?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Is it possible? I know you can get their city (with their permission), but can you get their country?

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about locale?  My locale is "en_US".  Can play around with it here:
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=1739831728%3Ffields%3Dlocale

EDIT:

Ehh, not a fan. My friend lives in Dubai and it returns "en_US" for him too:
https://graph.facebook.com/shivam.daryanani

Checkout this post: [Facebook Graph API - how to get user country?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5143483/facebook-graph-api-how-to-get-user-country)