# Facebook Graph API - get user home country

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to fetch user's country by user's hometown.

I am using the latest Graph API v2.3 and I know FQL is deprecated in this version, so I can no longer use [Facebook Graph API - how to get user country?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5143483/facebook-graph-api-how-to-get-user-country)

The only way is to do it by Graph API, but the tricky thing is

```
$fb_user = (new FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', '/me'))->execute()->getGraphObject(GraphUser::className());

var_dump($fb_user->getProperty('hometown'));
```

only returns the location Page id and name, then I do

```
$graph_obj_hometown = (new FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', '/' . $hometown_id, array('locale' => 'en_US')))->execute()->getGraphObject();

var_dump($graph_obj_hometown->asArray());
```

there is no country information in it, anyone knows how to get user's country?

Also, I have tried to get user hometown as a GraphLocation object then maybe I can use getCountry() method but it is still not working

```
$fb_user->getProperty('hometown', 'Facebook\GraphLocation');
```

the object only stored location name and location page id in the object.

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: You have to ask for the field first

Comment: @WizKid is right - try me/fields=hometown and make sure your app granted the permission user_hometown? If so you should get the pageId of the hometown in the following format:
{"hometown": {"id": "110769888951990","name": "Dublin, Ireland"},"id": "772082842826394"}

Comment: @Neil yes I already did, so I said "returns the location Page id and name"

Comment: @WizKid I already did

Comment: The `country` field is not mandatory. If you're lucky, it's there, if not, it's not.

Answer (score 0):

After getting the hometown page id, query:
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/HOMETOWN_ID?fields=location
The resulting object will contain the country.