# Get country name & timezone from facebook login in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, fbloginview

I am getting user data using `FBSDKGraphRequest` in facebook login from graph..

But don't know how to get timezone & only country name from that data..

what i coded till now is as follow:

```
FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]
                              initWithGraphPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@",result.token.userID]
                              parameters:@{ @"fields" : @"id, name, email, first_name, hometown, last_name, location" }
                              HTTPMethod:@"GET"];
[request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
    [self handleRequestCompletionWithResult:result error:error];
}];
```

Here I am getting data in result ..!!!

Comment: what are the permissions u request to Facebook

Comment: loginButton.readPermissions =@[@"public_profile", @"email", @"user_friends",@"user_hometown",@"user_location"];

Comment: i can add more permissions if necessary..!!!

Comment: you are added the correct permissions , but check on developer site are you enbaled these permissions or not

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5143483/facebook-graph-api-how-to-get-user-country

Comment: using location you can get users city and country, like 'Pune, India' in my case, then all you have to do is get the name after comma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about the country, but you can get the timezone by adding `timezone` to the fields. All the available fields can be found here: [User graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/)

BTW, `location` field should return the country.

Comment: New versions for Graph User api is [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/user)